# Menú de navegación

Tags: javascript, web

¡Hola comunidad de programadores!
Verán, tengo un problema respecto a mi menú de navegación (cabo aclarar qué este metódo sería ideal qué funcione en pantallas pequeñas y grandes) en dónde me gustaría qué el menú este pegado a la pantalla cuando el usuario haga scroll, pero... acá viene el problema, cuando el usuario haga scroll para abajo, qué este menú desaparezca y sólo aparezca cuando el usuario haga scroll para arriba (parte superior de la pantalla).
¿Alguna idea de como se podría hacer esto? Cabo aclarar que soy muy básico con js, pero intento día a día aprender nuevas cositas.

Answer (score 0):

```
let header = document.getElementById('id de tu header')
let scrollPos = window.pageYOffset

window.addEventListener('scroll', e =>
{
    if (e.path[1].scrollY > scrollPos) {

        header.style.display = 'none'
    } else {

        header.style.display = 'flex'
    }

    scrollPos = e.path[1].scrollY
})
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!